# Using variables from global sass stylesheet inside a sass module

Tags: css, sass, next.js

I think that the best practise is to have a global `.scss` file, with all the basic styles (like primary color etc.).
Then, for each React Component, you write it's own module, to keep it clean and the `.css` needed to import to a minimum.

Using this approach, I get a weird error though.

I have a `styles/global.scss` file with this:

```
$primary-color: #6dd3d6;

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

now I have another file called `NavBar.module.scss` with this content:

```
@import "styles/global";

.nav {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    background: $primary-color;
}
```

My `_app.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/global.scss'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

and my `NavBar.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './NavBar.module.scss';

export default function NavBar() {
    return(
    <nav className={styles.nav}>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    );
```

}

This gives me the following error:

```
./components/NavBar.module.scss:3:1
Syntax error: Selector "body" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

  1 | $primary-color: #6dd3d6;
  2 | 
> 3 | body {
    |                ^
  4 |     margin: 0;
  5 |     padding: 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `body` selector in a module as it says in the error message: "*Selector "body" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)*".

Create another Sass file that contains only variables and import it in the module / global Sass files.

Edit from Question Author to provide additional information:
It is also wrong to import the `global.scss` in any of the `.module.scss` classes, which caused the error. It is a global style, no need to reimport it.